# SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=SYSCAT.COLUMNS, DRIVER=3.54.54

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

Hi i'm trying to find column count for a db2 table. I have schema name and table name details.
Tried with

```
select COUNT(*) from SYSCAT.COLUMNS  WHERE TABNAME = 'ABC' and TABSCHEMA='XYZ'
```

AND

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('ABC')
```

But unfortunately both of them are throwing errors.

Need suggestions with my issue of finding column count for a table in db2 database

Comment: I had specified in the title

Comment: SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=SYSCAT.COLUMNS, DRIVER=3.54.54

Comment: are you sure it is db2 and not MSSql. Becuase sys.columns is a MSSQL system table. Is your DB2 database linked to a MSSQL db?

Comment: Ya it's db2 only. But why is my first query failing?

Comment: If there's no `SYSCAT.COLUMNS` then it's probably not DB2 for LUW.

Answer (score 1):

Hi finally i was able to fix this issue by modifying my query to

`select count(*) from sysibm.syscolumns where tbname = 'ABC' and TBCREATOR = 'XYZ'`

where TBCREATOR is the schema name and tbname is the table name.

Answer (score 0):

this code work on system i (AS400...)

```
 select * from qsys2.syscolumns                              
 where COLUMN_NAME='YOURCOLUMNNAME'                          
 and TABLE_NAME='YOURTABLENAME' and TABLE_SCHEMA='YOURLIB'
```